# Python. Программа в которой пользователь вводит список чисел. После обработки программа должна выводить список квадратов этих чисел

Tags: python, list, циклы

Помогите пожалуйста понять где ошибки и почему программа не работает

```
x=[]
x=input()
x=x.split()
for j in x:
    x[j]=int(x[j])
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i]=x[i]**2
print (x)
```

Comment: Разберись что у тебя х, что у тебя j; прочитай текст ошибки. Такое впечатление, что код наугад пишешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код неправильный во всем.
могу предложить свои варианты.
Если вы подаёте  в input() через запятую и пробел, то вот ваше решение:

```
x = input().split(', ') # вводите 1, 2, 3, 4
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = int(x[i]) ** 2

print(x) # получаете [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

или

```
print(list(map(lambda x: int(x) ** 2, input().split(', '))))
```

Если вы подаете в input() значение в виде списка ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), то вот ваш код

```
print(list(map(lambda z: z ** 2, list(map(int, input().replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(', ')))))) 
#при вводе [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] вы получите [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

а что вы от программы хотите? вы бы задачу написали

```
x=[] # зачем тут инициализирован список?
x=(input()) # зачем input взят в скобки - ОШИБКА
x.split() # результат разбития строки никуда не записывается
for j in (x): # опять круглые скобки - зачем? ОШИБКА
    x[j]=int(x[j])
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i]=x[i]**2
print (x)
```

разберитесь со скобками и переменными

Answer (score 0):

Ваши ошибки:

1. Лишние скобки `()` там, где они не нужны.
2. В 3 строке вы превращаете строку в список с помощью `split`, но не записываете это в переменную, т.е. переменная `x` у вас по-прежнему остается строкой, а не списком.
3. Строчка `x[j]=int(x[j])` -
   `j` это у вас число из списка, например, список `[5, 1, 2]`. Вы используете `j` как индекс, т.е. обращаетесь к элементу с индексом 5 (шестому элементу) в списке `[5, 1, 2]`, но такого элемента нет, либо это будет не тот элемент, который вам нужен. Вам нужен элемент списка со значением j, а не с индексом j. Обратиться к нему можно вот так: `x[индекс элемента j в списке x]` -> `x[x.index(j)]`

Либо вы можете написать этот цикл так же, как написали второй цикл:

```
for j in range(len(x)):
    x[j] = int(x[j])
```

Тогда `j` в этом цикле у вас будет не элементом списка, а индексом.

И лучше переменную со списком именовать не `x`, а, например, `inputed_digits`

```
x = []
x = input()
x = x.split()
for j in x:
    x[x.index(j)] = int(x[x.index(j)])
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i] ** 2
print(x)
```